# Difference between alias and branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new to version control and git.  I'm confused by `git push [alias] [branch]`.

What is the difference between an alias and branch?

Comment: Where did you see that description? In the manpage, paraphrasing, it says `git push <repository> <refspec>`, which makes it fairly obvious that you're pushing to a *repository*, and you're pushing a ref (branches and tags are refs). And yes, you can give repositories names - they're called remotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[alias]` is your **Primary remote repository**'s alias. And `[branch]` is your branch name of  the project.
For example, I have a repo(let's say, **yourRepo**) on github, and its primary remote repository is `git@github.com:user/yourRepo.git`.
You'll often do

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/yourRepo.git
```

to add it to your local repo. Then you can push your update to github by

```
git push origin master
```

Here `origin` is often used as alias for `primary remote repository`.

---

There're still some other type of alias for git. For example, you can do

```
git config alias.com commit
```

to make `com` alias to `commit`. The alias here is not the `[alias]` in your question. I just mentioned it by the way. Maybe you'll like it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

By `alias` I think you mean `repository`?

So a typical command you'd run might be `git push origin master`. Where `origin` is the name of the repository you are pushing to and `master` is the branch name to push.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own aliases for branches. If you feel for it, you can make an alias for the `master` branch called `sweet-mother-of-god`.